# Converting Month, Date, Year to FILETIME

Tags: date, winapi, format, filetime

Is there any function that converts a Month, Day, Year combination (e.g., "March 21, 2009"), to `FILETIME`? I don't mind doing it manually using a `SYSTEMTIME`, but anything Windows provides will be better than what I do.  Thanks for any info.

Comment: Parsing this (which is a result) is a bit too late (especially with localized Windows). How did you get that string in the first place? That probably was a PROPVARIANT initially.

Comment: Well I'll be regexing it from a standard Outlook pdf email header, which is formatted using a long date.  Actually I can probably regex for just the month, date, and year (and leave out the day of the week).  But I still wasn't sure if there was a function to get that to a FILETIME.  I assume I'll have to do it manually, which is fine.

Comment: So, it's not coming from the Windows Property System, is it? If it's not, then it's not necessarily a PDFF_LONGDATE per se.

Comment: Oh, yeah, then I guess I should rephrase the question.

Comment: You seem to be going the wrong direction. If you want data to be machine-readable, don't make it human-readable along the way. Parsing `March` is inherently harder than parsing `03`. I'm almost sure that you started out with a `FILETIME`. Keep that, and you won't have to apply a (lossy) conversion later on.

Comment: There are a few ways in Windows to do string->date conversion, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121102-00/?p=6183.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter - Thank you very much.  Not sure how I missed those.

Comment: @loop123123 you should always remember to check the official documentation, a.k.a. Raymond's blog ;)

Comment: Yes definitely.  If you want to make your comment an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.